# How to deserialize property with the name which is keyword?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, keyword

I have following XML code:

```
<sees direction="NE"/>
<sees direction="E"/>
<sees direction="SE">
    <object>diamond</object>
    <background>green</background>
</sees>
<sees direction="SW">
    <background>green</background>
</sees>
```

I have problem with deserialzation of object tag. First I wrote manualy property, then I used XSD tool to generate classes and also edited XMLElementAttribute.

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("object", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string @object
{
    get
    {
        return this.objectField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.objectField = value;
    }
}
```

I didn't found way to fullfill this field even when it compiles, and all the rest fields (for example background) work fine.

Is there something what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
[XmlElement("object")]
public string WhatEverNameYouLike {get; set;}
```